# How to store multiple List<NameValuePairs> for later post to server?

Tags: android, list, post, upload, storing-data

I want to be able to store multiple `List<NameValuePairs>` for when multiple users enter information into my Android application using the same device. Later on, the user should then be able to send their data to the server at a click of a button. But this should only be for later upload for example when there is wifi/network connectivity.

What is the best way to go about storing these `List<NameValuePairs>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to save everything as a long string of name value pairs seperated by ampersands for easy upload to database when sending to php server.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your best bet is to store the data in Android's SQLite database:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

As an alternative you can just serialize your objects to a file, but that might be too much of a hussle if the data is big.

Then you can have a service that runs in the background and sends data from the local db to the server when possible.

Comment: I'd rather store the List object rather than the data within the List. And yes I'd rather not save them to a big file either.

Comment: Well then I'm thinking you should make a helper class that does all the boiler-plate necessary SQL requests to store an instance of your list (and the elements it contains) to the DB.

Comment: What do you mean by storing an instance of the list?

Comment: I mean, the Object representing your particular List. You make a new object for your List (probablly new ArrayList()), you add NameValuePairs instances to it, you get the instance of your List

Comment: And how will the NameValuePairs be stored in the database?

Comment: WEll, that's what I was saying, you have to make your own utility that takes a List of NameValuePairs  objects, and makes the necessary SQL requests to store whatever pertinent data you need stored from it all. Like, your NamedValuePair might have 2 fields such as "name" and "value', so then you can make a table containing "name" and "value" columns in the db and sotre each NamedValuePair  as a row in that table.

Comment: I was just checking that I was understanding you correctly, which I did from your explanation. Storing name, value pairs like that isn't an option for me due to project requirements.

Comment: I've half decided to store the data using xml and post that. But I have to see if my client will be alright with that (fussy client). I'll get back to this once I know.

Answer (score 0):

Here are your storage options:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

I would imagine that depending on the kind of data and size, SharedPreferences or SqlLite could be useful for you. You can back DB with a `ContentResolver` and implement sync (`SyncService`) to upload to server. In this case, the Android OS will intelligently sync your data on the cloud when network is reachable.